# Blazor page doesn't re-render when API call happens too fast

Tags: javascript, .net, dom, blazor

I have a Blazor Server App in which one of the pages calls an API to fetch some data on Init.

My code behind:

```
page.razor.cs

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
  // await Task.Delay(350); // 350ms delay causes data to consistently render in the DOM
  await FetchData(); // makes an API call
}

public async Task FetchData()
{
    loading = true;

    var paginatedResponse = await MyService.Search(searchRequest); // API call

    records = paginatedResponse.Results;

    loading = false;
}
```

When running locally: the `FetchData()` call always gets fired and data is rendered in the DOM. No issues.

When deployed on the server: the `FetchData()` call works the **first time** but on subsequent visits to the page, the data from `FetchData()` is not rendered on load up.

As illustrated in the code sample, a short delay (350ms) will consistently cause the data to render in the DOM (on the server).

**My question**:
How can I get the data to consistently render without the use of a delay?

Comment: Post (an outline of) FetchData. It sounds like you have an 'async void' somewhere. Also look for "... is not awaited" warnings.

Comment: @HH posted FetchData

Comment: The code [that you've shown us] looks good. What else is going in Page.razor? Is that everything in `OnInitializedAsync`?  Are you doing things in `OnAfterRender`?

Comment: The only thing in OnAfterRender is a jsruntime call to a function that enables bootstrap popovers. (on first render only).

Comment: What exactly are "subsequent visits to the page" ?   Move `await FetchData(); ` from OnInit to OnParamsSet.

Comment: @HH "subsequent visits to the page" meaning: every page visit after I've opened up the browser and navigated to the page the first time. For instance, navigating to a different route then back to the route with "FetchData" is a subsequent visit. 

However, I believe it has to do with the fetchdata call happening too quickly.  I have tried moving it to OnParamsSetAsync to no avail.

Comment: "too fast" cannot be the issue in rendering. So it is something you did not post yet.  Try to make a [mre].

Comment: @HH correctly pointed out that this code was not the issue. The data was being rendered in a child component that had a boolean flag called "awaitingFirstRender" which wouldn't display the datatable until the first render. Removing that flag and any dependency fixed the issue of data not being rendered.